# Route 53 DNS Configuration only useful when you purchase from AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, subdomain, amazon-route53

I am new to DNS and AWS as well. I don't understand what exactly NS / CNAME / A. And I've purchased domain from goDaddy. Do I need to setup DNS at ROUTE 53 or I'll need to setup DNS at goDaddy?

So, I believe Route 53 DNS Configuration only useful when you purchase from AWS only.

And I need to setup DNS at goDaddy specially for Sub Domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Route 53 to create hostnames under your GoDaddy domain name. These might be pointing to public hostnames hosted in your amazon network. That's completely acceptable. You have to specify in GoDaddy that you are going to manage DNS externally.

A is an authoritative DNS record e.g. ip1.mydomain.com -> 1.2.3.4
CNAME is an alias e.g. ip1-alias.mydomain.com -> ip1.mydomain.com

Comment: Ok, It means I just need to VirtualHOST at httpd.conf file and then sub domain will start working. Right? But before that I'll need to check godaddy's configuration. That is fine.

Comment: Can I set sub domain (*.domain.com to ip?) DNS settings at goDaddy to point AWS EC2 instance?

Comment: If you are using Apache/NGINX, yes, you can have your public names point to the Public IP of the Apache/NGINX server, and from there you can route to other servers in AWS based on the name used in the URL.

Comment: Sub domain is different from a host in the domain. e.g. ip.domain.com is a host in your domain. ip.sub1.domain.com is a host in your subdomain sub1.

Comment: But anyhow I will need to point my sub domain to AWS Elstic ip right?

Comment: When you login into GoDaddy to manage your domain, there is an option to set external name server. Using that you can set aws name servers for one/more of your subdomains, which implies, all hostnames in that subdomain are being managed by an aws name server. You manage the subdomain hostname in AWS using route 53.

Comment: Sorry for asking too many questions. But Can I add *.domain.com for all subdomains settings in godaddy? I don't want to move DNS configuration to AWS now. I'll manage from godaddy. But for that I need to do entries for every sub domain? Also, I want to point to same ip which was pointing to main domain? is it fine?

Comment: You can still have everything in GoDaddy. Create all hostnames in GoDaddy DNS and just IP addresses of your Amazon instances. What are you looking to use Route 53 for?